# Minimize $(A\land\neg C)\lor(B\land C)$

Tags: logic

Is it possible to write following expression with each variable occuring only 1 time and using any of operations $\land\neg\lor\oplus$ ?

$$(A\land\neg C)\lor(B\land C)$$

Comment: Sorry if I'm not helpful, but you want each variable to occur only once and to have each of the 4 operators occur only once also? So excluding the $\neg$ operator you have 3 variables and only to positions for the operators. Something like this: $A?B?C$, where ? is one of the 3 operators $\land\lor\oplus$. Of course you can put $\neg$ in 4 positions , but putting the other 3 operator in before the first variable, or after the last one those not make much sense. Of course I'm not very good with these logical statements , and I maybe haven't understood your question right.

Comment: @randomname I think the problem as written does not require the *operations* to appear only once each, only the variable names $A,B,C$.

Comment: @randomname I meant only variables each once, operators any of listed in various count.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but...

That is equivalent to

$ \neg(\neg A \lor C) \lor (B \land C)$

$ \equiv \neg(A \to C) \lor (B \land C)$

$ \equiv (A \to C) \to (B \land C)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By brute enumeration it can be verified that no such formula exists.